# Número de decimales en una función SQL

Tags: sql

Estoy haciendo una consulta en mi base de datos para calcular un promedio y utilizo para ello la funcion `avg()`. Mi problema es que me devuelve muchos números después de la coma, ¿cómo puedo reducir esto a sólo uno o dos valores después de la coma?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hola Buenas noches es tan sencillo haciendolo de esta forma
 `SELECT round(avg(id_usuario),2) from principal.usuario as promedio`  se utiliza la clausula round la cual se le pasa un valor para redondear el resultado, en este caso esta sentencia me devolvera dos numeros despues de la coma, espero te sirva, buena noche..

Comment: muchas gracias !!!!!!!

Comment: Para eso estamos ,  compañero!!!

Answer (score 0):

Hey creo si le das SELECT round(avg(id_usuario),2) from principal.usuario as promedio se utiliza la clausula round la cual se le pasa un valor para redondear el resultado.
En este caso esta sentencia me devolvera dos numeros despues de la coma. Es todo lo que tengo/:

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).